# HTTP Error when uploading pictures in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, imagick

I get 500 errors when uploading pictures in Wordpress 4.2.2. on a box running Ubuntu 15.04 with Apache 2.4 and ISPConfig3. The server is set up according to: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-ubuntu-15.04-with-apache-php-myqsl-pureftpd-bind-postfix-doveot-and-ispconfig/

Everything is working fine except when uploading pictures over a certain size (~150 kb). The server has both imagick and GD addons installed.

php -v:
PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:29:28)

PHP -m:
http://pastebin.com/yM4efV6B

I have upped the limits in php.ini for upload size and post size, so that's not the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: open your index.php and type <?php echo phpinfo(); exit; ?>

Comment: and run your project and find imegic

Comment: open your php.ini and put extension=imagick.so

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did that, and added the line to php.ini, restarted apache2 -- but I still get the same error.

Comment: i thing wp-content/uploads folder permission change 777

Comment: I tried changing the permission to 777, but it still doesn't work. I doubt that's the problem though, as some smaller pictures upload fine -- while larger images over a certain size should be processed in imagick.

Comment: ok check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache

Comment: i thing change in this file httpd.conf

Comment: <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            # changed from None to FileInfo
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time. That post lead me to the solution:

I added MaxRequestLen 15728640

to

etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf

In case others are looking for the same

Comment: Thank you dear this is my blog site http://valabhavesh.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 5):

I added the line

> MaxRequestLen 15728640

to

> etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf

In case others are looking for the same. It seems to be a fairly common problem, and a lot of tricks to solve it using htaccess and plugins, but this one did it for me.

Comment: I had to use the `FcgidMaxRequestLen` field instead of MaxRequestLen and that did it.  See here: https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen

Answer (score 0):

Http Error Solution. Just Install the following Plugin. But take backup of your website first for any problem.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/